# Magento 2: Send transactional email(new signup, order creation, abandon cart) mailchimp

Tags: magento2

> Is it possible through mailchimp to send all emails(new signup, order
> creation etc)?
>
> Magento, mailchimp, Zandesk Sell which would be better for transactional emails?
>
> Please suggest for this
>
> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, you can install mailchimp for magento from here https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/releases and configure it.
You have a howto here https://mailchimp.com/en/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento-2/
And you can use automation in mailchimp for sending transactional emails